# Receiving nameserver set by passing one NS

Tags: php, dns, nameservers, dig

Is there a way to recieve the complete nameserver set by passing just one nameserver of the set?

For example I pass the the Nameserver: ns1.sedoparking.com and as a result I would expect

`ns1.sedoparking.com + ns2.sedoparking.com`

I tried it already with the Pear function "Net_DNS_Resolver", DIG and `dns_get_record("ns1.sedoparking.com", DNS_ANY, $authns, $addtl)`

But I receive always the wrong nameservers.

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PHP's DNS functions do not allow you to specify which server to query, I'd just use `dig` (I have no previous experience with `Net_DNS_Resolver`), and query specifically for the NS records:

```
dig ns1.sedoparking.com ns @ns1.sedoparking.com +noall +answer
```

Outputs:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.1-P2 <<>> ns1.sedoparking.com ns @ns1.sedoparking.com +noall +answer
;; global options: +cmd
ns1.sedoparking.com.    86400   IN  NS  ns1.sedoparking.com.
ns1.sedoparking.com.    86400   IN  NS  ns2.sedoparking.com.
```

However, it's somewhat rare the nameservers return NS records when you query them with their own name, so I'd just remove the `ns1` part from the query to make sure:

```
dig sedoparking.com ns @ns1.sedoparking.com +noall +answer
```

The answer will be the same in both cases.

Comment: Thank you a lot, this was the way I looked for!